# IndexedDB location in Windows 8 Application

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro, indexeddb

So i am working on this HTML5/JavaScript metro application for windows 8.1 with Indexed Db for storing metadata.

I need to locate the physical file for the database.
I have tried looking at "C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Indexed DB\" but of no use.

Where i should be looking ?

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2011/11/indexed-db-deleting-your-database.html) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c8b59d8b-e172-49a4-8bc9-68c588425b36/indexeddb-app-file-location?forum=winappswithhtml5) suggests:

Firefox:

```
<location of the windows user profiles>\<account name>\AppData\Roaming\
Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<some random characters>.default\IndexedDB
```

Chrome:

```
<location of the windows user profiles>\<account name>\AppData\Local\Google\
Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB
```

IE:

```
C:\Users\<<USER>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Indexed DB\
```

Comment: i need to get the location of database used in my metro application not for FireFox/IE/Chrome

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. So [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c8b59d8b-e172-49a4-8bc9-68c588425b36/indexeddb-app-file-location?forum=winappswithhtml5) is not what you're looking for?

Comment: if not, try out [this one](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/guest-posts/2012/08/27/finding-the-local-storage-folder-of-a-windows-8-style-application)

Comment: Grevling thanks for the suggestion, but i have already checked the app's local storage folder and the installed folder and got nothing there.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know. Good luck :)