# How to cache audio file delivered from CloudFront using JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, audio, audio-streaming

We are developing an online course website. 
Courses have audio and text (no video). 
Audio files are stored on Amazon S3 and delivered via AWS CloudFront.

Every time a user wants to play a course audio file, 
website (server-side) sends a request to CloudFront to get the audio file. 
CloudFront will deliver the audio file to the end-user (HTTTP response).

We use JPlayer to play the audio files.
Audio file format is MP3

We are facing the following issue:

Every time a user clicks on play/pause, forward, rewind buttons OR 
jumps to a specific position on the audio player, 
a new request (for the same audio file) is being sent to CloudFront, 
so audio player position is reset to 00:00

Since CloudFront already delivered the audio file to end-user, 
there is no need to generate a new request to CloudFront 
every time user clicks on audio player buttons (play/pause, forward, rewind) etc.

So once user gets the audio file from CloudFront, 
we want to cache the audio file.

**How can we store an audio file in local browser cache using JavaScript or jQuery?**

Comment: How big are the audio files?

Comment: Average size of audio file is 5 MB.

Comment: [This link](https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/) goes into the standard ways of storing data on the client browser side.  Honestly it sounds like there is an issue with your streaming setup and I've never heard of a 5 second token lifespan but perhaps you can use one of these storage methods.

Comment: The token is used to verify that only authorized users get access to audio files located in CloudFront. Once CloudFront delivers the audio file to end-user, I need to store this audio file somewhere locally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching audio files should be done using browser caching.

There are several ways to implement "browser caching".

Huge thanks for "stdunbar" for sharing the following link. 
This link points to a great article that provides 
an overview of the different browser caching solutions. 
https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/

For my use-case, the optimal solution for audio file caching is **IndexedDB**.

Here are some great articles on how to get-started with IndexedDB (IDB):

Basic concepts 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB

Path locations in different browsers 
[IndexedDB location in Windows 8 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354791/indexeddb-location-in-windows-8-application)

Tutorial 1 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_indexeddb.htm

Tutorial 2 
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/

Tutorial 3 
http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/12/23/html5-storage-indexeddb/